# How to swap widget placement in a tkinter grid using drag and drop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to swap the placement of two widget in a grid layout in tkinter using drag and drop. On mouse ButtonRelease-1 I want to get the widget over which the mouse was released (myTextLabel2), so that I can change the row and column of that widgets with the row and column of the clicked widget (myTextLabel1).

I tried search for the method that gets the widget at position x,y, put all I can find is the reverse, getting the position of widget not the other way arround.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def changeOrder(widget1,widget2):
    widget1.grid(row=1,column=0)
    widget2.grid(row=0,column=0)

def drag_start(event):
    print(event.x)

def drag_motion(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    

def drag_release(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    #I want to get the widget at position x,y, should be myTextLabel2

    #Then swap the rows and columns for myTextLabel2 and myTextLabel1
    

root = Tk()


myTextLabel1 = Label(root,text="Label 1")
myTextLabel1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)
myTextLabel1.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
myTextLabel1.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)
myTextLabel1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",drag_release)


myTextLabel2 = Label(root,text="Label 2")
myTextLabel2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)


myButton = Button(root,text="Change order",command=partial(changeOrder,myTextLabel1,myTextLabel2))
myButton.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def changeOrder(widget1,widget2,initial):
    target=widget1.grid_info()
    widget1.grid(row=initial['row'],column=initial['column'])
    widget2.grid(row=target['row'],column=target['column'])

def on_click(event):
    widget=event.widget
    print(widget) 
    if isinstance(widget,Label):
        start=(event.x,event.y)
        grid_info=widget.grid_info()
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda event:drag_motion(event,widget,start))
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",lambda event:drag_release(event,widget,grid_info))
    else:
        root.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

def drag_motion(event,widget,start):
    x = widget.winfo_x()+event.x-start[0]
    y = widget.winfo_y()+event.y-start[1] 
    widget.lift()
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)

def drag_release(event,widget,grid_info):
    widget.lower()
    x,y=root.winfo_pointerxy()
    target_widget=root.winfo_containing(x,y)
    if isinstance(target_widget,Label):
        changeOrder(target_widget,widget,grid_info)
    else:
        widget.grid(row=grid_info['row'],column=grid_info['column'])

root = Tk()

myTextLabel1 = Label(root,text="Label 1",bg='yellow')
myTextLabel1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)

myTextLabel2 = Label(root,text="Label 2",bg='lawngreen')
myTextLabel2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)

myButton = Button(root,text="Change order",command=partial(changeOrder,myTextLabel1,myTextLabel2))
myButton.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)

root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

- `root.bind("<Button-1>",on_click)` has been used to bind the entire window with the `<Button-1>` event, the function `on_click` adds the other 2 bindings if the widget clicked is an instance of `Label`. The `grid_info()` of the label is stored and passed accordingly.
- `drag_motion` changes the position of the widget based on motion using `place`, and keeps the widget on top using the `lift` method.
- `drag_release` lowers the widget using the `lower` method followed by obtaining the current position of the cursor using `winfo_pointerxy` method and passing the returned value to the `winfo_containing` method which returns the widget under the mouse pointer.

You can replace the `isinstance` logic by storing the widgets that are swappable in a list and then then checking if the widget lies in that.

PS: The button in your original post would not work due to the changes made to the code.

Comment: For the button to work now, you would have to pass `myTextLabel2.grid_info()` as the last parameter, even after that it would work correctly only once due to the changes in the function. I don't think that's a part of the question anyway.

Comment: @CoolCloud Will do, thanks for pointing out.